# Haskell - Form a matrix based on a list Matrix

Tags: haskell

I would to make a haskell function that takes a list of Item Ratings(a data type I declared), looking like this:

```
[[NoRating,R 5.0],[R 5.0,R 4.0],[R 3.0,R 1.0]]
```

the declaration of Rating looks like this:

```
data Rating c = NoRating | R c deriving (Show, Eq)
```

in the list each sublist represents ratings belonging to a user, each sublist contains multiple items, in the previous example 2 items were in the sublist,

What I would like to return is a list of item rating differences from a matrix like input, The value at row i and column j represents the sum of the differences between the ratings given to item i and item j by the same user

for example, for the input

```
dMatrix [[NoRating,R 5.0],[R 5.0,R 4.0],[R 3.0,R 1.0]]
```

I would like to return

```
[0.0,3.0,-3.0,0.0]
```

I have already implemented a difference function that takes 2 ratings and returns the difference, it looks like this, would be nice to use it through

```
differenceRatings :: Fractional a => Rating a -> Rating a -> a
differenceRatings NoRating (R a) = 0
differenceRatings (R a) NoRating = 0
differenceRatings  (R a) (R b) = a - b
```

I'm having a hard time implementing this because the only way I know to loop in haskell is recursion but in this instance I need to do in a specific matrix order and access multiple sublist items of same index at same time, thanks for your help.

[image]

Picture as like example, first we do column 0 with column 0, difference is 0,
then we do column 0 with column 1, rating of item 0 for user 1 - item 2 for user 1, and so on for user 2 and 3 then sum them, put that in the second index of result list
then we do column 1 with column 0, negative of what is before generally
lastly column 1 with column 1, difference is 0

I have drafted this code and tried it but am getting a type error

```
dMatrix :: Fractional a => [[Rating a]] -> [a]
dMatrix [] = []
dMatrix x = dMatrixH1 x 0 0
dMatrixH1 (x:xs) i j = (dMatrixH x:xs i j) ++ (if (j < ((length (x:xs))-1)) 
then dMatrixH (x:xs) i (j+1) else if (i < ((length xs)-1)) then dMatrixH 
(x:xs) (i+1) 0 else 0)
dMatrixH [] _ _ = 0
dMatrixH (x:xs) i j = (differeneRatings (x!!i) (x!!j)) + dMatrixH xs i j
```

Comment: "*What I would like to return is a matrix*" - then why is your return type a plain list of numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure why the problem i'm trying to solve refers to it as a matrix honestly, I also think it's just a list but possibly he's expecting me to flatten a matrix into a list? whatever achieves the example is good for me, i'll update with the textbook problem.

Comment: added an example

Comment: How exactly do you want to traverse your matrix? It is a bit weird that you input a 3x2 matrix, but the result is a list of 4 elements.

Comment: As I explained, for the 2 columns, first you are on element (0,0) so you compare column 0 with column 0, then (0,1) column 0 with column 1, so on with (1,0) and (1,1). picture i added in the end + example  should kinda explain

Comment: Added an attempt code i made, if fixed i believe would work

Comment: `differeneRatings x!!i x!!j` parses as `((differeneRatings x) !! (i x)) !! j`. Spacing doesn't affect precedence. Also, `differeneRatings` is undeclared.

Comment: @OmarHussein: but then what is the third row doing here?

Comment: the differenceRatings in the question was declared as differeneRatings in my file but it's the same, added brackets and now this is the error im getting, post updated with new code

Comment: ERROR file:.\lmaogetrektson.hs:75 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : xs i j
*** Term           : xs
*** Type           : [[Rating [d]]]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c

Comment: `dMatrixH x:xs i j` parses as `(dMatrixH x) : (xs i j)`. Same problem.

Comment: @melpomene I have (x:xs) in paranthesis, what do you mean I should do?

Comment: Can you please first explain how you obtain the list of values. What elements are you comparing in what way in the result?

Comment: The elements I am comparing are of type Rating which I show in the beginning of the question, the list is input into winhuggs as shown in the example and the function I use to compare is shown in the question...

Comment: Winhugs? Do you know that there hasn't been a new release of hugs in 12 years?

Comment: it's what we use at uni i'm sorry it's outdated lol, don't see why that should be a reason to have any problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using 2 of my helper functions, posting them first

```
matrixPairs :: Num a => a -> [(a,a)]
matrixPairs 0 = []
matrixPairs c = matrixPairsH 0 0 (c-1)
matrixPairsH a b c = [(a,b)] ++ if ((b == c) && (a == c)) then [] else if (b == c) then (if (a==c) then [] else matrixPairsH (a+1) 0 c ) else matrixPairsH a (b+1) c
```

and

```
differeneRatings :: Fractional a => Rating a -> Rating a -> a
differeneRatings NoRating (R a) = 0
differeneRatings (R a) NoRating = 0
differeneRatings NoRating NoRating = 0
differeneRatings  (R a) (R b) = a - b
```

and here's the code for the required function

```
dMatrix :: Fractional a => [[Rating a]] -> [a]
dMatrix [] = []
dMatrix (x:xs) = dMatrixH (x:xs) (matrixPairs (length x))
dMatrixH _ [] = []
dMatrixH x ((a,b):ys) = [(dMatrixH2 x a b)] ++ dMatrixH x ys
dMatrixH2 [] _ _ = 0
dMatrixH2 (x:xs) a b = (differeneRatings (x!!a) (x!!b)) + dMatrixH2 xs a b
```